# How to reduce the scrolling speed of the flex mobile SpinnerList component

Tags: apache-flex, mobile, scroll

I'm using the SpinnerList component in a flex mobile application, the spinner turn too fast for my need, is it any way to reduces its speed.

There is many answer regarding the speed of the mouse wheel but no answer concerning the spinner itself.

Comment: You want to control the scroll speed ?

Comment: SpinnerList is designed primarily for mobile applications, presumably with touch input.  Isn't the scroll speed directly affected by the swipe?  Shorter swipes move slower and scroll slower.  Longer swipes move faster and quicker.  I think you'll have to quantify what "too fast" means and how you're interacting with the SpinnerList.

Comment: Yes, that's right, the speed of the gesture influences the speed of the spinnerList. So maybe I didn't ask my question properly. Maybe, the parameter that I want to control is the inertia of the spinnerList? But anyway, in either case, independently of the move I do, the spinnerList scoll too fast for my need and I would like to be able to reduce the speed or inertia of the scrollingList.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did a quick look into flex source:

I think the SpinnerList scrolling is used by a normal Scroller just as with the a normal List component.

The Scroller class uses a TouchScrollHelper class. This class contains a calculateThrowVelocity() and this method uses some constants like VELOCITY_WEIGHTS

However, this method and consts are all private, so you won't be able to modify it by extending the class. Furthermore, the touchScrollHelper property in Scroller is private as well.

So, I'm afraid the only way to modify the speed/inertia is to create a custom Scroller using a custom TouchScrollHelper by copying most of the code from the originals, but a custom calculateThrowVelocity() You can add your custom Scroller to the SpinnerList using a skin.